# Can the Midrash be included in "Talmud Yerushalmi"

Tags: words, midrash, talmud-yerushalmi

When saying or writing "Talmud Yerushalmi" can this include (or refer to) the Midrash

For example.
In [the Tanya (Chabad) chapter 37](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7916/jewish/Chapter-37.htm) it says

> ובכל תלמוד ירושלמי היא נקראת בשם מצוה סתם

But it was only  [once](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Horayot.17b.3) or [twice](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Peah.2b) found in the Talmud Yerushalmi, but it is a few times in the Midrash ([1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.36.3) and [2](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.1.1)) , is it possible that the words Talmud Yerushalmi include the Midrash?

Souce please

Related https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=26814
And
http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/mahanaim/agadot-1-2.htm

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean to be included in "the midrash"?

Comment: @DoubleAA anything

Comment: THere are Midrashim that are later than the JT, hence the JT is mentioned.

Comment: one of those links has a link to this pdf: https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=33117&sid=1717180c663c3ec99eed02d8437e8f12 -- It goes through a bunch of sources that discuss how Mitzvah refers to Tzedakah

Comment: No, not since after the era of the Rishonim are *medrashim* sometimes referred to as "talmud (medrash) Yerushalmi (Eretz Yisroel)".

Comment: @Oliver please elaberate

Comment: @Menachem but in yerushushalmi only 1

Comment: @hazoriz Forgive the apparent vagueness. I meant: "No, [the words Talmud Yerushalmi] do not [include the Midrash], not since after the era of the Rishonim." The medieval rabbis, even Geonim, would refer to a 'Talmud Eretz Yisroel' (or 'Yerushalmi') when speaking of a *midrash* (or, occasionally, to older kabbalistic works) which was compiled in EY. But, that tendency ceased with the Rishonim. An example: Rashi, [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8961&st=&pgnum=278), cites 'Yerushalmi' and as Buber notes we don't have such a Yerushalmi, though it is a *midrash* (Ex. Rab. 8:3).

Comment: @Oliver that is an answer for me, (that in the time of the rishonim talmud ... Was the way some refered to the midrash(but later they stopped)) and if you bring more sorces i will b"n accept your answer

Comment: @hazoriz The general rule said by the the Lubavitcher Rebbe, and he fills the place of the Alter Rebbe, is that he says, (and how much more so that he writes,) what he means. When he wrote in the Tanya, "in the whole Talmud Yerushalmi...", he did not mean midrash, but only Talmud Yerushalmi.